# Running TCL code (on an existing TCL shell) from Python

Tags: python, shell, tkinter, tcl

**Introduction**

I recently started working on a legacy product, under Linux, which incorporates a builtin TCL shell. Due to company limitations, I can't gain control to "behind the scenes" and all of the code I can write must be run under this TCL shell, handling the pre-defined clumsy TCL API of the product.

I found myself wondering a few times whether it will be possible to patch some Python into this setup, as some solutions seem more legitimate in Python than in TCL. By patching Python I mean: either calling the Python code from the TCL code itself (which can be done with *Elmer*, for example), or to use Python from outside of the product to wrap the TCL API (for which I found no "classic" solution).

**The Problem**

Given that the product already **has** an existing TCL shell *in it*, most solutions I browsed through (e.g. *Tkinter*) can't be used to run the TCL code from Python. I need to "inject" the code to the existing shell.

**Solutions Considered**

As a solution, I thought about bringing up a simple server on the TCL side which runs simple commands it receives from the Python side. I wrote a small demo and it worked. This enabled me to write a nice, class based, wrapper in Python for the clumsy TCL API, also manage a command queue, etc.

Another two solutions I thought of is forking the software from Python and playing with the read/write file descriptors or connecting through FIFO rather than a socket.

However, I wondered whether I'm actually doing it right or can you suggest a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`quickdraw.py` is a code example where Python function calls are automatically translated into quickdraw commands and piped into the corresponding java process](https://gist.github.com/zed/a011754fa77737e099b7#file-quickdraw-py). The point is that [the rest of the Python code](https://gist.github.com/zed/a011754fa77737e099b7#file-main-py-L173) doesn't need to be aware that there is a java subprocess invovled. Sockets are more powerful and more portable than pipes (sockets may work with `select()` even on Windows) though pipes might be simpler in some cases.

Comment: [pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect) perhaps

Comment: If the Tcl shell you have supports the even loop, you could simply use the Tcllib comm package to connect a python `tkinter.Tcl()` interpreter with the Tcl shell and send commands via TCP/IP. Afterwards just wrap the tkinter wrapper in your Python code and be done. (see http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/comm/comm.html and if you want, the wire protocol is documented too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: 
If you just want a class based OO system to write your code in, you don't need python, Tcl can do OO just fine. (built in with 8.6, but there are quite a few options to get OO features, classes etc. in older versions too, e.g. Tcllibs [SNIT](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/snit/snit.html%20SNIT) or [STOOOP](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/stooop/stooop.html)

If you still feel Python is the superior tool for the task at hand (e.g. due to better library support for some tasks), you can 'remote control' the Tcl interpreter using the Tcllib comm package. This needs a working event loop in the Tcl shell you want to control, but otherwise it is pretty simple to do.

In your Tcl shell, install the Tcllib comm package.
(ask again if you need help with that)

Once you have that, start the comm server in your Tcl shell.

```
package require comm
set id [::comm::comm self]
# write ID to a file
set fd [open idfile.txt w]
puts $fd $id
close $fd
proc stop_server {} {set ::forever 1 }
# enter the event loop
vwait forever
```

On the python side, you do nearly the same, just in Tkinter code.

Basically like this:

```
import Tkinter
interp = Tkinter.Tcl()
interp.eval('package require comm')

# load the id
with open('idfile.txt') as fd:
    comm_id = fd.read().strip()

result = interp.eval(
    'comm::comm send {0!s} {1!s}'.format(comm_id, '{puts "Hello World"}')
```

Using that python code and your shell, you should see `Hello World` printed in your shell.

Read the comm manual for more details, how to secure things, get callbacks etc.  [comm](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/comm/comm.html)

If you don't like the tkinter burden, you can implement the wire procotol for comm too, should not be too hard in Twisted or with the new async support in Python 3.x.
The on the wire protocol is documented in:
[comm wire protocol](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/comm/comm_wire.html)

Comment: Thanks!
Isn't there a mistake in the first line (`set srv [::comm:comm]`) as `::comm::comm` expects an argument and you don't really use `srv`, or am I missing something?