# tcl error "expected floating point number but got"

Tags: tcl

I am using tcl with the OpenSees program (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114714/call-different-interpreter-for-tcl-in-python/37151296#37151296) question). One command offered by OpenSees in TCL is `block2D` and its syntax is as follows:

```
block2d $nx $ny $e1 $n1 element elementArgs {
1 $x1 $y1 <$z1>
2 $x2 $y2 <$z2>
3 $x3 $y3 <$z3>
4 $x4 $y4 <$z4>
}
```

In my specific case I am doing the following:

```
#geometric parameters
set nx 4
set ny 2
set elwidth 1.0
set elheight 1.0
set blockwidth [expr $nx*$elwidth]
set blockheight [expr $ny*$elheight]

block2D $nx $ny 1 1 quad "1 PlaneStrain2D 1" {
    1 0.0 0.0
    2 $blockwidth 0.0
    3 4.0 2.0
    4 0.0 2.0
}
```

Where the variables used in the `block2D` command are set in the beginning. Unfortunately when I run this script I get the following error:

```
WARNING block2D numX? numY? startNode? startEle? eleType? eleArgs?: invalid node coordinate for node: 1
expected floating-point number but got "$blockwidth"
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Other OpenSees commands allow for passing in variables. Why would this one be any different?

I have already tried different variants and nesting of the `expr` and `eval` commands on the `blockwidth` variable... All to no avail ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've asked for an unsubstituted literal in this command:

```
block2D $nx $ny 1 1 quad "1 PlaneStrain2D 1" {
    1 0.0 0.0
    2 $blockwidth 0.0
    3 4.0 2.0
    4 0.0 2.0
}
```

That's what being in `{`braces`}` *actually* means. Which would be fine except you want a substitution in it. There are several sensible ways to do this:

### Use a `"`double-quoted`"` word

```
block2D $nx $ny 1 1 quad "1 PlaneStrain2D 1" "
    1 0.0 0.0
    2 $blockwidth 0.0
    3 4.0 2.0
    4 0.0 2.0
"
```

### Use the `subst` command

```
block2D $nx $ny 1 1 quad "1 PlaneStrain2D 1" [subst {
    1 0.0 0.0
    2 $blockwidth 0.0
    3 4.0 2.0
    4 0.0 2.0
}]
```

### Use `list` to build the list

```
block2D $nx $ny 1 1 quad "1 PlaneStrain2D 1" [list \
    1 0.0 0.0 \
    2 $blockwidth 0.0 \
    3 4.0 2.0 \
    4 0.0 2.0 \
]
```

This third option is probably the best in terms of performance, but the second is probably more readable (despite being slowest), especially if you don't like using multi-line “strings” like the first option.

Comment: the quotes did it. Thanks